# What hook to use for loading a custom class extension during Theme initialization?

Tags: theme-development, customization

I'm trying to organize some things in my custom theme, and so I'm using `require` to load in some custom classes I've created that implement native WordPress classes.  When I code the class right into my theme's `functions.php` file, everything is hunky-dory... but move the class into a `THEMEDIR/utilities/extendWalker.extension.php`  I get an error that the dependent Interface (the `WP_NAV_WALKER` from `/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`) can't be found... even though it does indeed exist in that location.

I can only surmise that I need to be loading externally defined classes on one of the action hooks during theme initialization, but which one?  I've tried to search the codex, but searching codex or google for something like this will get you a thousand results you don't want.  I need to make sure my theme is built properly, so things like nav menus work properly.. and I'm afraid to use the plugin hooks.

What's the best hook to use for theme utility classes?  (stuff you might look to do via your `functions.php` file)

I'm currently getting it to work using:

```
add_action('plugin_init','loadMyClass');
function loadMyClass(){
    require_once THEMEDIR . '/utilities/myclass.php'
}
```

but don't want problems down the road with conflicts cause by scripts from plugins installed by the users or site admins.

Comment: Do I get it right, you basically just took a part of your `functions.php` and put it into another file/directory that is included in your `functions.php`?

Comment: yes.  I had a class defined in `functions.php` that extended wp core classes, and they worked fine until I moved them out of the functions file.  It loads my class, but can't find the class I'm extending.

Comment: Can you get me some access to your code? Hard to guess this way.

Comment: Have you got the right link? Does not work for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12775/discussion-between-fischi-and-brian-vanderbusch)